# Unable to mount XP share: Error NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL

Tags: mount, samba, vpn, windows-xp, share

I'm failing with mounting XP share, receiving message:

> ...
>
> mount error(110): Connection timed out
>
> Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

When I try to list shares with **smbclient**, finally I receive message:

> ...
>
> Running timed event "tevent_req_timedout" 0x7f2902964ad0
>
> Error connecting to 192.168.34.140 (Success)
>
> lang_tdb_init: /usr/share/samba/en_US:en.msg: No such file or
>
> directory
>
> Connection to 192.168.34.140 failed (Error NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL)

I wasn't able to find solution, could anyone advise?

**Context**:

- I'm trying to mount share of **NT-domain** machine with XP which is accessed via VPN. While my ubuntu machine is still in default **WORKGROUP**. Is this possible at all?
- Connection to target machine could be established, f.e. I can connect to it via RDP.
- Command executed to mount:
  `mount -t cifs //192.168.34.140/share_name /media/share_name -o username=XPDomainUsername,password=XPDomainPassword,workgroup=XPDomainName`
- Command executed to list shares:
  `smbclient -L //192.168.34.140 -U XPDomainName\\XPDomainUsername --debuglevel=10`

Comment: What's the command you're running?

Comment: To mount: mount -t cifs //192.168.34.140/share_name /media/share_name -o username=XPDomainUsername,password=XPDomainPassword,workgroup=XPDomainName

Comment: To list shares: smbclient -L //192.168.34.140 -U XPDomainName\\XPDomainUsername --debuglevel=10

Comment: It seems, that this is firewall issue, and file sharing ports are blocked for VPN connections. I can telnet on 445'th port of my XP machine from LAN, while I can't telnet the same via VPN, getting timeout exception:
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

Comment: I also had this problem, and specifying both hostname and IP solved it.

Answer (score 4):

You might have to specify the IP address separately because most Windows servers require you to specify the NetBIOS name too, e.g.

```
smbclient -L XPHostName -I 192.168.34.140 -U XPDomainName\\XPDomainUsername --debuglevel=10
```

Comment: Thanks Jelmer. But unfortunately, filesharing via VPN is restricted in my network.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of searching I found a [solution](http://ubuntuswitch.wordpress.com/2010/02/05/nautilus-slow-network-or-network-does-not-work/), which worked for me.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Sometimes comments to answers are more valuable than the answer.